# The enums does not get passed to TCL when we have SWIG TCL Static Linking

Tags: c++, enums, tcl, swig, static-linking

In continuation to question

[how to pass enum values from TCL script to C++ class using Swig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058170/how-to-pass-enum-values-from-tcl-script-to-c-class-using-swig)

I have following code

1) File : example.i

```
%module example
%{
      /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
      #include "example.h"
%}

%include "example.h"
```

2 File example.h

```
class myClass {
    public:
        enum Type {one,two};
         myClass() {}
        static bool printVal(int val);
        static bool printEnum(Type val);
};
```

3) File example.cpp

```
 #include  "example.h"
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 bool myClass::printVal(int val) {
    cout << " Int Val = " << val << endl;
    return 0;
 }

 bool myClass::printEnum(type val) {
    cout << " Enum Val = " << val << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

If I link the  swig files in the form of shared library it is working fine

```
swig -c++ -tcl example.i
g++ -c -fpic example_wrap.cxx example.cpp -I/usr/local/include
g++ -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o example.so
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /pathtoexample.so:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
tclsh
% load example.so
% myClass_printVal $myClass_one
```

But if the swig code and example.* files are linked statically I am getting following error

```
 % myClass_printVal $myClass_one
 can't read "myClass_one": no such variable
```

Looking forward for guidance/help

Comment: How exactly are they linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly,** if you use more of the path to the shared library, you don't need to alter the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. In the case that it's in the current directory (convenient for testing) you can just do this:

```
load ./example.so
```

When it's in the same directory as the current script, you instead do this rather longer version:

```
load [file join [file dirname [info script]] example.so]
# This also probably works:
#load [file dirname [info script]]/example.so
```

**Secondly,** you should check what the example has actually created; it might simply be using a different name to what you expect. You can use `info commands`, `info vars` and `namespace children` to find this out; they list the commands, variables and namespaces currently visible.

*[EDIT from comments for visibility]:* The variables are in the `::swig` namespace.

Comment: Irritatingly, my installation of SWIG is choking when I try to actually build and run the tests. It's not your code, it's a problem with my system configuration…

Comment: Yes The global variables are coming inside swig:: namespace . Thanks it helped .